# json.dump object rename attribute before the dump

Tags: python, json

I am currently serializing my custom object into a JSON string by using `json.dumps()`.

```
j = json.dumps(object, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '),
               default=lambda o: o.__dict__)
```

My object has an attribute called `_machines`. So when we turn the object into a string one of the properties in the string is called `_machines`. Is there any way to tell `json.dump()` that we want this property to be called `machines` rather then `_machines`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use a more elaborate default:

```
json.dumps(object, sort_keys=True,indent=4, separators=(',', ': '), 
           default=lambda o: {'machines' if k == '_machines' else k: v for k, v in o.__dict__.iteritems()})
```

It might be a good idea, for the sake of readability, to make that a separate function:

```
def serialize_custom_object(o):
    res = o.__dict__.copy()
    res['machines'] = res['_machines']
    del res['_machines']
    return res

json.dumps(object, sort_keys=True,indent=4, separators=(',', ': '), 
           default=serialize_custom_object)
```

Here, `serialize_custom_object()` is a little more explicit that you are renaming one key in the result.

Comment: just a quick comment I was doing this in python3. so __dict__.iteritems() no longer exists. So instead that part should become __dict__.items() except for that it worked perfectly thanks a lot

Comment: Yup, I was indeed assuming Python 2 and forgot to add the usual disclaimer about using `dict.items()` on 3 instead.