# How to convert Object with Properties to JSON without "_" in Python 3?

Tags: python, json

I would like to convert an Python object into JSON-format.

The private attributes of the class *User* are defined using properties. The method *to_Json()* I have found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/python-how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable)

```
class User:
  def __init__(self):
      self._name = None
      self._gender = None

  @property    
  def name(self):
    return self._name     

  @name.setter    
  def name(self, name):
      self._name = name

  @property    
  def gender(self):
      return self._gender     

  @gender.setter    
  def gender(self, gender):
    self._gender = gender

  def to_Json(self):
      return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__, allow_nan=False, sort_keys=False, indent=4)
```

The output using this class and method is:

```
{
  "_name": "Peter",
  "_age": 26
}
```

What is the easiest way to get rid of the underscores in the JSON-format? (I want "name" instead of "_name") Removing the underscore in the class is not an option since I get an error (max. recursion depth). I think renaming the methods of the attributes would solve this problem, but is this the best solution here?

Renaming all keys before the json.dumbs (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925166/json-dump-object-rename-attribute-before-the-dump)) is not a practical approach because I my class is more complex than the above example.

So, what is the best practice to convert a Python object into JSON-format as fast as possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the example code you posted mirrors your real code, there really isn't any reason for the properties at all.  You could just do:

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.age = None
```

since you're not really hiding anything from the user behind the underscores and properties anyway.

If you *do* need to do the transformation, I like to do it in a custom encoder:

```
class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        return {k.lstrip('_'): v for k, v in vars(o).items()}

json_encoded_user = json.dumps(some_user, cls=MyEncoder)
```

Comment: I wanted to use properties to do some value checks or further formatting. Thank you for the code snippet.

Answer (score 7):

In Python, you'd normally *not* use properties for basic attributes. You'd leave `name` and `age` to be directly accessible attributes. There is no need to wrap those in `property` objects unless you need to transform the data when getting or setting.

If you have good reasons to use attributes with underscores but reflect them as JSON dictionaries, you can transform your dictionary when converting to a dictionary:

```
object_dict = lambda o: {key.lstrip('_'): value for key, value in o.__dict__.items()}
return json.dumps(self, default=object_dict, allow_nan=False, sort_keys=False, indent=4)
```

Note that this does nothing to prevent collisions. If you have both a `_name` and a `name` attribute on your instance, you'll clobber one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but I had private fields with two underscore characters.

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self.__id

    @id.setter
    def id(self, id):
        self.__id = id

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        self.__name = name
```

Therefore, my json encoder is slightly different

```
from json import JSONEncoder


def beautify_key(str):
    index = str.index('__')
    if index <= 0:
        return str

    return str[index + 2:]


class JsonEncoder(JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, o):
        return {beautify_key(k): v for k, v in vars(o).items()}
```

Full answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251861/4587961).