# json dumps with private fields

Tags: json, python-3.x

I would like to serialize users into json. User has only private fields.

**user.py**

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self. set_id(id)
        self.set_name(name)

    def set_id(self, id):
        self.__id = id

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name
```

**json_encoder.py**, without it `json.dumps` does not work.

```
from json import JSONEncoder


class JsonEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        return o.__dict__
```

**user_app.py**

```
import json
from json_encoder import JsonEncoder
from user import User

def main():
    users = build_users(names) # a function that returns list of users
    users_json = json.dumps(users, indent=4, sort_keys=True, cls=JsonEncoder)
    print(users_json)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It prints

```
[
    {
        "_User__id": 0,
        "_User__name": "Alex"
    },
    {
        "_User__id": 1,
        "_User__name": "John"
    }
]
```

Which is almost good. I would like, however, to have private fields as field names - without class name prefix.

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Alex"
    }
]
```

Is there annotation, or should I write custom helper to customize json output.

By the way, is it a good practice to make private fields in python? I come from Java world, where we do prefer private fields.

### Update

[How to make a class JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable) partially answers my question. How to serialize it with beautiful properties names, see example of my output, I still have to learn more. I did not know how customize **JsonEncoder**. I posted my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a class JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable)

Comment: Since you already have a custom encoder, why not put the custom field names there?

Comment: You'd have to write a custom JSONEncoder - `_User__id` is the *actual name* of the attribute, name mangling is how Python implements privacy.  Note that it isn't particularly Pythonic to use setters/getters at all, just access the attributes directly.  (If you do find a need to execute code on set/get, you can add that after the fact via `@property`.)

Comment: @rdas how to put custom field names?

Comment: Instead of returning `o.__dict__`, build a dictionary from the `id` & `name` from `o`. You'll need getters for `id` & `name`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709364/jasonharper) So far, I found [example about properties and setters](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php) Now I know how to do encapsulation in python.

**user.py**

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self.__id

    @id.setter
    def id(self, id):
        self.__id = id

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.__name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        self.__name = name
```

Next, I need to [serialize it into JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813111/how-to-convert-object-with-properties-to-json-without-in-python-3).

**json_encoder.py**

```
from json import JSONEncoder


def beautify_key(str):
    index = str.index('__')
    if index <= 0:
        return str

    return str[index + 2:]


class JsonEncoder(JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, o):
        return {beautify_key(k): v for k, v in vars(o).items()}
```

Now the output is correct for me.

```
[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Alex"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "John"
    }
]
```